# php code return the current page

Tags: php

I wrote this code `<form action="saisi.php" method="post">` on the page `saisi.php` and I was wondering if there is some php code which returns the current page without using it's name, as you can see from my code the action page is the same page where there is the form.

Comment: What do you mean by "return the current page"?  You want the contents of the PHP file you are currently running?  You want to know the output HTML?  You want the title?  What do you mean by "without using its name"?  Do you simply want the constant for the current script?

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >

Answer (score 2):

By default if you leave action to be blank it will post to the same page.

Also be sure to check $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and other php vars in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```